# Alter table with GO results in syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, t-sql, syntax-error

I have been scratching my head for a while with this error.

The following script:

```
alter table t alter column c int
GO
```

Results in error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
```

What I mainly want is to embed this script inside of a longer script hence the need to execute the transaction before the rest of the script proceeds. I have also tried it with and without semicolons and that makes no difference.

I would appreciate any kind guidance.

Same error in SQL server 2016 and 2019. I am running SQL in SSMS interactively. The existence of the table does not make a difference to the error. I have tried it with the following DDL:

```
create table t (c float)
```

screenshot is here.[image]

screenshow with SELECT then GO showing that other statements with GO work fine.
[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253629/discussion-on-question-by-paolov-alter-table-with-go-results-in-syntax-error); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: One thing to understand is `GO` is not actually part of the SQL language. It's a batch separator provided by whatever tool you're using, and not something processed by or sent to SQL Server itself. If the particular tool doesn't know about this separator, it will cause invalid syntax. Additionally, even within SSMS, which is the most common place to use this, the batch separator is _configurable_. You could change it to be something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue with a SQL file that uses Macintosh line endings (CR instead of CR LF or LF):

[image: The document opened in Notepad++]

[image: Query opened and executed in SSMS]

The solution is to convert the line ending to Windows [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/menu-help/advanced-save-options?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: The issue is not due to line endings The OP is on windows. There is clearly a difference between ALTER TABLE t ALTER COLUMN vs ALTER TABLE t ADD or other DDL statements that change the column count. The former errors with syntax error if you put a GO after it. The latter does not error and in fact requires a GO. if you don't there is a different error.

Comment: No one has been able to reproduce the issue you're facing (see comments in chat). The closest is to change batch separator in SSMS but it would result in a red squiggle below `GO` and the error you mentioned, but you've said it is not the case. Newline issue is the closest I got.

Comment: Does writing an ALTER TABLE t ALTER COLUMN statement with a batch separator (GO) and  an ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN with a batch separator (GO), with each of both of those followed by an INSERT statement compile and execute for you? I.e. ALTER followed by INSERT with GO in between.

Comment: Yes it does....

Comment: You have actually tried both? And both compile and run? do you have a screenshot?

Comment: like so (2) https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlbHK.png

Comment: Thanks. I tried it again just now and very mysteriously it didn't error. I did not change anything.

Comment: Then it could have been a non printing character that you copy-pasted from somewhere. CR is my guess. Other characters should cause visual studio to display the red swiggle below GO.

Comment: @paolov: In this case you can also mark this answer as accepted as also others assume it's just a non-visible wrong line break (like only LF instead of e. g. windows LFCR) which caused the problem (while the script itself is obviously correct and not the real issue).

Answer (score -1):

As of me your code is correct. Just try with remove Comment & after `GO` make sure that no space are available.

```
ALTER TABLE t ALTER COLUMN c int;
GO
ALTER TABLE t ALTER COLUMN c int;
GO
```

Comment: Check the comments, you'll find OP has been through all these options.

Comment: Just let me know what i tell is define in comments?

Comment: semicolons is enough, just remove GO